# Extract digit after or before a specific word

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I have several articles about terrorist attacks which include info of the number of people killed and wounded. I am trying to extract the number concerning the people wounded.

This is a sample of the sentences to target:

```
at least 22 others were wounded
additional 20 soldiers were wounded
more than 40 people had been wounded
wounding at least six people
injuring at least 60 others
wounding more than 25
27 others were wounded 
wounding 14
wounding 33
185 people were wounded
28 people wounded
```

As you can see the wordS wounded, wounding,injuring are either before or after the digit I want to extract, ususally within 3 or 4 words of distance from the number.

In this link you can find a sample of the articles and the regualr expression that I am trying to apply without success:
[Regex] (https://regex101.com/r/0DRayP/10)

Comment: Have a try with [this rather large regex using 2 groups for capturing the digits](https://www.regex101.com/r/2Xysjd/2) (with pcre feature *branch reset* [one group could be used](https://www.regex101.com/r/2Xysjd/3) -> [python regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)). Here [another version with a combination of matching and capturing inside lookahead](https://www.regex101.com/r/2Xysjd/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks, the second is pretty solid. Could you explain it in details?

Comment: Which one solid? :p Please tell link. On the fly right now I can explain in the evening. Btw in the first (and second) there was a mistake, [it should be like this](https://www.regex101.com/r/2Xysjd/4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capturing groups to get into groups your desired matches like:

```
(\d+)?.*?(wound(?:ed|ing)|injured).*?(\d+)
```

You are interested in groups $1, $2 and $3

Here is an example:

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DiBSjQ/2)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue is that when I apply it on the whole documents it extracts more than the information of interest. https://regex101.com/r/0DRayP/11